# Не могу понять объявление цикла FOR в одном из методов стандартной библиотеки

Tags: java, циклы

Попался на глаза цикл FOR в методе `getColumnName` класса `AbstractTableModel`.
Собственно, вот он:

```
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    String result = "";
    for (; column >= 0; column = column / 26 - 1) {
        result = (char)((char)(column%26)+'A') + result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

`(; column >= 0; column = column / 26 - 1)` - вот это мне не понятно.

Хотелось бы увидеть разъяснения.

Версия java  "1.8.0_102".

Comment: а что именно непонятно?

Comment: @Grundy видимо напугало отсутствие чего-либо в statement1, где обычно пишут `int i = 0` =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну и третий блок, в принципе, тоже не обычный `i++`

Comment: Обычные математические операнды, получаемый параметр count из конструктора метода, а не как привычно видеть int i = 0

Comment: @Grundy, как и второй. `for(;;);` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данный цикл выполняется до тех пор, пока условие `column >= 0` истинно. На каждой итерации цикла значение переменной `column` изменяется в соответствии с выражением:

```
column = column / 26 - 1
```

Возможно Вас смутило то, что в записи цикла `for` отсутствует инициализация каких-либо переменных – это нормальная практика. Бывают ситуации, когда инициализировать здесь ничего не нужно.

Теперь по поводу действий непосредственно внутри цикла:

```
result = (char)((char)(column%26)+'A') + result;
```

Здесь происходит:

- вычисление значения `column%26` – остатка от деления `column` на `26`;
- `(char)(column%26)` – явное преобразование полученного в предыдущем пункте значения к типу `char`;
- `(char)(column%26)+'A'` – происходит сложение кодов символов `(char)(column%26)` и `'A'`;
- `(char)((char)(column%26)+'A')` – результат предыдущего действия преобразуется к типу `char`;
- происходит конкатенация результата предыдущего действия со строкой `result` (*причем производится она плохо*).

Comment: `(;` -  это выражение как понять? Если можете, перепишите этот цикл нормальным циклом **for**, для сравнения.

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff, он и есть нормальный. В нём дважды встречается `;` и любая из трёх частей необязательна. Да хоть все 3: `for(;;)System.out.println("Hi from infinite loop!");`

Answer (score 3):

циклы в java объявляются следующим образом:

```
for(инициализация переменных; условия для остановки; действие выполняемое на каждом шаге){
     // тело цикла
}
```

Собственно, каждая конструкция в цикле может отсутствовать.
Вот такой цикл является вполне валидным и компилируемым

```
for(;;);
```

В вашем случае, было пропущена инициализация переменных.

Comment: `определение переменных` - вообще-то нет :)

Comment: Не "определение переменных", а скорее "инициализация". Которая может включать в себя и определение переменных в том числе. А может и вообще не требоваться, и тогда будет пустой.

Comment: Ага, согласен, небольшая неточность, поправил. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я не смотрел объявление этого класса, но, похоже, этот метод мог быть бы объявлен как `static`.

Чтобы метод был более читабельным я заменил магическое число 26 на выражение `'Z' - 'A' + 1`.

Кроме того в методе используется излишнее приведение типов, которое, как мне представляется, можно безболезненно убрать.

В результате получится следующий метод

```
static public String getColumnName(int column) 
{
    final int N = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;

    String result = "";

    for (; column >= 0; column = column / N - 1) 
    {
        result = (char)( column % N +'A') + result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Чтобы было проще понять, что этот метод делает, можно запустить демонстрационную программу.

/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    static public String getColumnName(int column) 
    {
        final int N = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;

        String result = "";

        for (; column >= 0; column = column / N - 1) 
        {
            result = (char)( column % N +'A') + result;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 702; i++ ) 
        {
            System.out.print( getColumnName( i ) + " " );
            if ( ( i + 1 ) % 26 == 0 ) System.out.println();
        }           
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN AO AP AQ AR AS AT AU AV AW AX AY AZ 
BA BB BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ BK BL BM BN BO BP BQ BR BS BT BU BV BW BX BY BZ 
CA CB CC CD CE CF CG CH CI CJ CK CL CM CN CO CP CQ CR CS CT CU CV CW CX CY CZ 
DA DB DC DD DE DF DG DH DI DJ DK DL DM DN DO DP DQ DR DS DT DU DV DW DX DY DZ 
EA EB EC ED EE EF EG EH EI EJ EK EL EM EN EO EP EQ ER ES ET EU EV EW EX EY EZ 
FA FB FC FD FE FF FG FH FI FJ FK FL FM FN FO FP FQ FR FS FT FU FV FW FX FY FZ 
GA GB GC GD GE GF GG GH GI GJ GK GL GM GN GO GP GQ GR GS GT GU GV GW GX GY GZ 
HA HB HC HD HE HF HG HH HI HJ HK HL HM HN HO HP HQ HR HS HT HU HV HW HX HY HZ 
IA IB IC ID IE IF IG IH II IJ IK IL IM IN IO IP IQ IR IS IT IU IV IW IX IY IZ 
JA JB JC JD JE JF JG JH JI JJ JK JL JM JN JO JP JQ JR JS JT JU JV JW JX JY JZ 
KA KB KC KD KE KF KG KH KI KJ KK KL KM KN KO KP KQ KR KS KT KU KV KW KX KY KZ 
LA LB LC LD LE LF LG LH LI LJ LK LL LM LN LO LP LQ LR LS LT LU LV LW LX LY LZ 
MA MB MC MD ME MF MG MH MI MJ MK ML MM MN MO MP MQ MR MS MT MU MV MW MX MY MZ 
NA NB NC ND NE NF NG NH NI NJ NK NL NM NN NO NP NQ NR NS NT NU NV NW NX NY NZ 
OA OB OC OD OE OF OG OH OI OJ OK OL OM ON OO OP OQ OR OS OT OU OV OW OX OY OZ 
PA PB PC PD PE PF PG PH PI PJ PK PL PM PN PO PP PQ PR PS PT PU PV PW PX PY PZ 
QA QB QC QD QE QF QG QH QI QJ QK QL QM QN QO QP QQ QR QS QT QU QV QW QX QY QZ 
RA RB RC RD RE RF RG RH RI RJ RK RL RM RN RO RP RQ RR RS RT RU RV RW RX RY RZ 
SA SB SC SD SE SF SG SH SI SJ SK SL SM SN SO SP SQ SR SS ST SU SV SW SX SY SZ 
TA TB TC TD TE TF TG TH TI TJ TK TL TM TN TO TP TQ TR TS TT TU TV TW TX TY TZ 
UA UB UC UD UE UF UG UH UI UJ UK UL UM UN UO UP UQ UR US UT UU UV UW UX UY UZ 
VA VB VC VD VE VF VG VH VI VJ VK VL VM VN VO VP VQ VR VS VT VU VV VW VX VY VZ 
WA WB WC WD WE WF WG WH WI WJ WK WL WM WN WO WP WQ WR WS WT WU WV WW WX WY WZ 
XA XB XC XD XE XF XG XH XI XJ XK XL XM XN XO XP XQ XR XS XT XU XV XW XX XY XZ 
YA YB YC YD YE YF YG YH YI YJ YK YL YM YN YO YP YQ YR YS YT YU YV YW YX YY YZ 
ZA ZB ZC ZD ZE ZF ZG ZH ZI ZJ ZK ZL ZM ZN ZO ZP ZQ ZR ZS ZT ZU ZV ZW ZX ZY ZZ
```

Итак, этот метод генерирует некоторые имена (метки колонок). Как он генерирует?

Рассмотрим для примера произвольное число 71. Чтобы получить крайний левый символ берется остаток от деления на 26, что соответствует выражению `'Z' - 'A' + 1`  Для этого числа получаем

```
71 = 2 * 26 + 19
```

Числу 19 ( это выражение в теле цикла `(char)( column % N +'A')` ) соответствует буква `'T'`

При делении `71` на `26` мы получили `2`.  Значит перед буквой `'T'` будет присутствовать еще одна буква. Но так как индексация букв идет от 0, а не от 1, то из этого выражения вычитается 1

```
column = column / N - 1
```

В результате получаем `1`, которая соответствует букве `'B'` (`'A' + 1 = 'B'`) и будет получена в теле при следующей итерации цикла. После этого при делении 1 на 26 будет 0, то есть нет более значений которые содержат еще одну группу из 26 символов. Поэтому получаем, что условие цикла

```
column = column / N - 1
```

даст отрицательное число, и цикл закончится.